# TFX CSVExampleGen component: How to read data with "|" as separator?

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

I am trying my way at TensorFlow's TFX. I have a CSV that contains the pipe symbol (|) as a field separator instead of the default comma. How can I specify this when using the CsvExampleGen component?

```
tfx.components.CsvExampleGen(input_base=data_path)
```

I tried using

```
example_gen_pb2.Input
```

But I did not find any read options to specify